# How do I avoid memory leaks from array list event listeners?

Tags: android, arraylist, memory-leaks, android-memory, leakcanary

I am getting a memory leak notification via leak canary where it says my fragment instance leaks due to references held from eventlisteners and Arraylist.array. Not sure how to fix this, any ideas?

```
@Override
ArrayList<myInterface> getnewList() {
    ArrayList<myInterface> inst = new ArrayList<>();
    inst.addAll(myRepository.getList());
    inst.addAll(myRepository.getOtherList());
    Collections.sort(inst, myRepository.myComparator);
    return inst;
}
```

Here's the leak trace which gives an indication of the leak:

```
In com.myproject.project2.alpha.debug:3.0.0:3000000.
* com.project.newzy.dashboard.myListFragment has leaked:
* GC ROOT static com.myproject.repository.myRepository.eventListeners
* references java.util.ArrayList.array
* references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
* leaks com.project.newzy.dashboard.myListFragment instance

* Retaining: 251 KB.
* Reference Key: cc806908-52f6-42f5-be98-b39665dfa218
* Device: samsung samsung SM-J327P j3popltespr
* Android Version: 6.0.1 API: 23 LeakCanary: 1.5.1 1be44b3
* Durations: watch=5463ms, gc=131ms, heap dump=3776ms, analysis=40370ms

* Details:
* Class com.myproject.repository.myRepository
|   static eventListeners = java.util.ArrayList@587750272 (0x23085b80)
|   static Comparator = com.myproject.repository.myRepository$5@587741136 (0x230837d0)
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[40]@584327169 (0x22d42001)
|   static initialized = true
|   static lock = java.lang.Object@587741152 (0x230837e0)
|   static cache = java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@587732480 (0x23081600)
* Instance of java.util.ArrayList
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[16]@1893860329 (0x70e203e9)
|   static MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT = 12
|   static serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189
|   array = java.lang.Object[12]@591375616 (0x233fad00)
|   size = 1
|   modCount = 1
|   shadow$_klass_ = java.util.ArrayList
|   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
* Array of java.lang.Object[]
|   [0] = com.project.newzy.dashboard.myListFragment@596231392 (0x2389c4e0)
|   [1] = null
|   [2] = null
|   [3] = null
|   [4] = null
|   [5] = null
|   [6] = null
|   [7] = null
|   [8] = null
|   [9] = null
|   [10] = null
|   [11] = null
* Instance of com.project.newzy.dashboard.myListFragment
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[16]@583464961 (0x22c6f801)
|   static serialVersionUID = 0
|   static $change = null
|   adapter = com.project.newzy.dashboard.DashboardAdapter@590877408 (0x233812e0)
|   myRepository = com.myproject.repository.myRepository@587661072 (0x2306ff10)
|   inst = java.util.ArrayList@591400160 (0x23400ce0)
|   emptyLayout = android.widget.RelativeLayout@593542144 (0x2360bc00)
|   emptyMessage = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@593544192 (0x2360c400)
|   floatingActionButton = android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton@594071552 (0x2368d000)
|   roomList = com.project.gui.advancedrecyclerview.AdvancedRecyclerView@593541120 (0x2360b800)
|   selectedVGroupID = null
|   listAdapter = com.project.newzy.dashboard.DashboardAdapter@590877408 (0x233812e0)
|   listDivider = com.project.newzy.base.helpers.DividerItemDecoration@589723120 (0x232675f0)
|   listManager = android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@591052128 (0x233abd60)
|   listView = com.project.gui.advancedrecyclerview.AdvancedRecyclerView@593541120 (0x2360b800)
|   mAdded = true
|   mAnimationInfo = null
|   mArguments = null
|   mBackStackNesting = 0
|   mCalled = true
|   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
|   mChildFragmentManager = android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl@588818688 (0x2318a900)
|   mChildNonConfig = null
|   mContainer = android.support.v4.view.ViewPager@597927936 (0x23a3a800)
|   mContainerId = 2131755178
|   mDeferStart = false
|   mDetached = false
|   mFragmentId = 2131755178
|   mFragmentManager = android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl@598589728 (0x23adc120)
|   mFromLayout = false
|   mHasMenu = false
|   mHidden = false
|   mHiddenChanged = false
|   mHost = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@598610224 (0x23ae1130)
|   mInLayout = false
|   mIndex = 1
|   mInnerView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@593536000 (0x2360a400)
|   mIsNewlyAdded = false
|   mLoaderManager = null
|   mLoadersStarted = true
|   mMenuVisible = true
|   mParentFragment = null
|   mPostponedAlpha = 0.0
|   mRemoving = false
|   mRestored = false
|   mRetainInstance = false
|   mRetaining = false
|   mSavedFragmentState = null
|   mSavedViewState = null
|   mState = 5
|   mTag = java.lang.String@590080848 (0x232beb50)
|   mTarget = null
|   mTargetIndex = -1
|   mTargetRequestCode = 0
|   mUserVisibleHint = true
|   mView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@593536000 (0x2360a400)
|   mWho = java.lang.String@591143744 (0x233c2340)
|   shadow$_klass_ = com.project.newzy.dashboard.myListFragment
|   shadow$_monitor_ = -2032154546
* Excluded Refs:
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedView
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedInputConnection
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
| Field: android.os.UserManager.mContext
| Field: android.net.ConnectivityManager.sInstance
| Field: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue (always)
| Thread:FinalizerWatchdogDaemon (always)
| Thread:main (always)
| Thread:LeakCanary-Heap-Dump (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.WeakReference (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.SoftReference (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.PhantomReference (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.Finalizer (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference (always)
```

Please let me know if you guys have faced this before and have any clues about how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Can you post the exact message please?

Comment: just added the trace :)

Comment: how do you get stace using Canary leaks? @MarissaNicholas just curious.

Comment: you integrate it with your project and when you run your app, it runs alongside as a separate app, tracking the leaks in the app as you navigate screen by screen

Comment: its very easy to integrate aswell, just a couple of lines of code

Comment: There is a good article about Memory Leaks on nimbledroid blog http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html
Read it and think about all the cases you can have in your application

Comment: Can you tell, which class implements `myInterface`?

Comment: Can you post skeleton of your interface, list fragment and myrepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the `com.myproject.repository.myRepository` is holding a reference to `com.project.newzy.dashboard.myListFragment` in the `eventListeners` array.

I'm not sure exactly what your `myRepository` is but (probably it used as an `Observable`) it's holding a reference to an `myListFragment` (probably a `Fragment`) that the `UI` needs to destroy.

To solve the issue you need to ensure that when the `myListFragment` is about to be destroyed it's no longer part of the `eventListeners` array. Just remove the listener from the array in `onPause` and register it back in `onResume`.

[image: Fragment Lifecycle]

Comment: I am already extending myListfragment from a base class called BaseListFragment. In that baseclass I have myrepository eventlistener added in onstart and I remove it on onStop. Isn't that sufficient? Should i also remove it in the subclass which is mylistfragment? Can it be done on onstart and onstop or does it have to be onpause and onresume in the sub class?

Comment: @MarissaNicholas No, `onStart` and `onStop` should do the work just fine. You are mentioning that you are adding, the `eventlistener`, in `onStart` and  removing in `onStop`? Or the activity/fragment? You should remove the activity/fragment itself from the `eventlistener` when the `onStop`  method of the activity/fragment is called.

Comment: so I have onstart and onstop both in the parent class "BaseListFragment" and the sub class " mylistfragment". however, I just add the listener for myrepository in onstart of the parent class and remove it onstop of parent class, I dont add or remove anything onstart and onstop of the subclass so far. Is it necessary for me to add it and remove it onstart and onstop of subclass too or create onresume and onpause methods in subclass to do so?

Comment: @MarissaNicholas No, you don't need to add and remove from fragment too. But from the leak report I see that `myListFragment` is added in the repository `eventListeners` array. That is why I said that you need to remove the `myListFragment` from the array when the fragment is paused/stopped.

Comment: I am little lost, so I should continue adding and removing the myrepository listener in onstop and add it on start of the parent fragment as i am currently doing? but at the same time in mylistfragment which is the subclass, i should do the same again ?

Comment: @MarissaNicholas No, if you should do it only in one place. But since you are getting a leak probably you are not removing it properly or adding it from somewhere else too. I would try and change the logic, and only add and remove the fragment in fragment's `onStart` and`onStop`, not in the base class. Also adding some log messages would help to see  when something is added and removed.

Comment: i did, but still see that issue recurring

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151329/discussion-between-dan-and-marissa-nicholas).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `myRepository` class holds a reference to a Fragment instance `myListFragment`.

I do not know the implementation of `myRepository` but if I can make a guess, this class is probably a Singleton class so it resides in memory for the whole application process. Fragment and Activity context is a big memory chunk and since a Singleton class holds a reference to that memory, Garbage Collector cannot clear that Fragment/Activity memory when it finishes its lifecycle which means your Fragment instance will also reside in memory throughout the whole application lifecycle. One blog about meomory leak: https://android.jlelse.eu/memory-leak-patterns-in-android-4741a7fcb570

I can recommend one fix to your problem:

1. Make your data manager class dumb and stateless. Do not attach a listener inside your data manager class. Instead, make API to make CRUD operations to data and only attach listeners in Fragment class. When an event is triggered, call data manager's methods accordingly. This makes your data manager not mix logic with any specific Fragment class which you do not need to change anything should you need to remove Fragments later in the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a memory leak from a listener from myrespository which is coming from a library which I am currently using in my code. 
I do add and remove the listener in onstart and onstop method in the baseclass of the fragment I use respectively. However, it shows a leak in leakcanary saying it was defined as a static variable that leaked. How do I address this?